# Xcode Error: Unable to install <app>Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile

Xcode had an auto update and it hung at the end. I responded by deleting it, rebooting my computer and reinstalling Xcode. Now, whenever I try to run something whether it's on a simulator or actual device, I get this:

Details

```
Unable to install <app>
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653179
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-04-03 19:41:11 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
Could not write to the device.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653179
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000005)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010e94cb1c DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 300
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010e981000 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 136
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010381bac8 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010e980d7c -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1208
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010cf3bce8 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.147 + 2340
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000103926428 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000103926e94 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 152
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a18bd9dc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a18bf504 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a18c6bbc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a18c7708 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a18d234c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a1a42100 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a1a40e20 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone15,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.2 (20C65)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 28558;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402653179";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.0 (Build 22A8380)
Xcode 14.3 (21812) (Build 14E222b)
Timestamp: 2023-04-03T13:41:11-06:00`
```

I've found multiple other problems here with similar issues, but none with the code I'm getting. This is developed in React Native and when I'm trying to sign for this app, I get another error:

```
Failed to register bundle identifier
The app identifier "org.reactjs.native.example.<app>" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
```

I've tried deleting and redownloading Xcode a second time, redoing my npm installs and my pod installs. I've tried signing with a different account, but still I'm getting the same error. How to fix this?

Comment: Have you figured it out?